# Question about passing a JavaScript method

Tags: javascript, methods

I have a quick question about below JavaScript code:

```
<script>
var numbers1 = [56, 234, 6, 5, 63, 265] ; 
var sum = numbers1.reduce(myFunction) ; 

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "The sum is " + sum ; 

function myFunction(total, value){
return total + value ; 
}
</script>`
```

I don't know why this code generates the sum of all elements in an array because we are only passing the definition of myFunction() to reduce() without specifying what goes into variables "total" and "value".
Also, what is going into those variables respectively?

Thank you so much for your help in advance !

Comment: Because `.reduce` executes `myFunction` on every element of the array and reuses the result from previous calls (in the `total` parameter)

Answer (score 0):

By default, calling `reduce()` with a callback function will pass these two variables (best known as the accumulator and current value) to the callback function. This is the case here: `myFunction` gets the accumulator and current value on every iteration. Even if you successively nest several functions in `myFunction`, the result will be the same:

```js
var numbers1 = [56, 234, 6, 5, 63, 265];
var sum = numbers1.reduce(myFunction);

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "The sum is " + sum;

function myFunction(total, value) {
  return myMiddleFunction(total, value);
}

function myMiddleFunction(total2, value2) {
  return myInnerFunction(total2, value2);
}

function myInnerFunction(total3, value3) {
  return total3 + value3
}
```

```html
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

Comment: That's a good answer with detailed explanation. I would edit it and remove the whole nesting part - it adds unneeded complexity.

Comment: Thank you for the example code and explanation guys. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Btw, is there a study material or resource where I can learn this level of details that you can recommend?

Comment: I think MDN has all what you need. Their documentation is very instructive.

Comment: @GuyLevinger the OP is asking where from the accumulator and current value are getting their values. The nesting part helps clear this.

Comment: @WaisKamal, thank you again for the tip !

Comment: Glad to have helped!